# Where do I specify the URL to test for my load testing project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, load-testing

When we create a WebAndLoadTestProject in VS 2013, the only place where I can specify the URL that I actually want to test is by adding a Web Performance test to the project and specifying the URL in the recording tool.

Does this mean that I cannot have a load test without having a web performance test?

Because I've searched a lot and I don't find any other place where I can specify the URL that I want to test.

And all the blogs that are out there also talk about having both the web performance test and the load test together. I never come across a single one that explains having a load test without a web performance test.

So my question is; Can I or can not I have a load test without a web performance test? If I can, then where do I specify the URL that I want to test against ??

Comment: Same question asked here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2cbfc44b-98af-4390-b8bb-32c95d446dda/where-do-i-specify-the-url-to-test-for-my-load-testing-project?forum=vstest

Answer (score 0):

I had to add the namespace Web before my URLToTest attribute.

```
<TestMethod(), HostType("ASP.NET"), Web.UrlToTest("Url")>
```

Comment: Maybe your answer is helpful, but you should probably provide a bit of explanations on its use.